# Following Tutorial, Index Scan failed

Tags: postgresql

[image: Turoial]

Above picture is one tutorial link.
But I use another table. The results attached below. I think the result will show the same as **Index Scan using...**. But the result is **Seq Scan**, which means it will scan the data one by one. But Why.
[image: my personal test]

Comment: A sequential scan can be faster than an index scan. And it looks like in your case this is the best approach: The database reads 10430 rows and removes 5696 rows from the results. That means it needs about 50% of your data. An index scan is most likely slower. You can check this by turning of the seq_scan: SET enable_seqscan TO off; and try explain again

Comment: Don't post text as images.  The first one returned 1 row (out of all unknown number).  The second one returned 2/3 of the table.

Comment: The execution plan is a lot easier to read if  you post it as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) rather than a screen shot